# What's the fastest way to append pytorch completions onto their original seeds?

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm starting with a 2d tensor, composed of n seeds, tokenized. I then generate prediction logits and sort them using argsort(), and then take the top m candidates. I'm looking for the best way to append each of these predictions onto the seed which generated it, and create a new 2d tensor that now has n * m seeds, where each seed is now one token longer. I'm new to torch, and wondering if it has a built in vectorized way of doing this

Here's the pseudo-code for what I want it to do

```
def predict(seeds, coherence_threshold, batch_size=16):
    """Takes in a tensor of tokenized seeds, outputs a tensor of tokenized seeds with completions"""

    dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(seeds, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)

    new_seeds = torch.tensor([], dtype=int)
    with torch.no_grad():
        for batch in dataloader:
            batch_tensors = reference_gpt2(batch)
            batch_preds = batch_tensors.argsort(descending=True)
            batch_preds_pruned = batch_preds[:,-1,:coherence_threshold]
            # TODO come up with a more efficient way to do this
            for i in range(len(batch)):
                for j in range(len(batch_preds[i]))
                    new_seed = torch.concat((batch[i], batch_preds[i,j]))
                    new_seeds = torch.concat((new_seeds, [new_seed]))
                    
    return(new_seeds)
```

Answer (score 0):

To append PyTorch completions onto their original seeds in the fastest way possible, you can use the torch.cat() function. This function concatenates tensors along a given dimension, and can be used to efficiently append one tensor to another.

Ex:

```
import torch

# Assume that original_seed and completion are both tensors of shape (batch_size, sequence_length)
concatenated = torch.cat((original_seed, completion), dim=1)
```